# Magento Product "created_at" Date Format Keeps Changing

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql, products

Any time a product is updated and saved, its "created_at" entry in the "catalog_product_entity" database table is updated to the format YYYY-DD-MM, but it should keep it as YYYY-MM-DD. The date/time do not change, only the format. It isn't a big problem in itself, but it is creating problems when I attempt to sort products by creation date.

Here is an example:

- created_at before: 2015-04-10 13:21:09 (YYYY-MM-DD)
- edit and save product via Magento
- created_at after: 2015-10-04 13:21:09 (YYYY-DD-MM)

Extra information: It is a Magento 1.9.1 store with the locale set to English (US) and timezone set to Los Angeles. The products from the store were originally imported via Magento's Import/Export feature from a wooCommerce store. Let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Did you move your store from one server to another at some point?

Comment: Yes, quite recently.

Comment: Are you on share hosting or dedicated?

Comment: Shared server with cPanel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use

```
Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()
```

instead of

```
$zendDate->getIso()
```

below is the solution.

open following file :
**app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Time\Created.php**

and comment out beforeSave() function and replace with following function code.

```
  public function beforeSave($object)
{
    $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();

    $date = $object->getData($attributeCode);

    if (is_null($date)) {
        if ($object->isObjectNew()) {

            $object->setData($attributeCode, Varien_Date::now());
        }
    } else {
        // convert to UTC
        $zendDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->utcDate(null, $date, true, $this->_getFormat($date));

        // Replace -> $zendDate->getIso() with Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate()
        $object->setData($attributeCode, Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: This appears to change the created_at date to the time the product is updated.

Comment: Commenting out the entire else statement appears to solve the issue for me.

Comment: have you checked in database table what value is going there while commenting entire else statment ?

Comment: If you comment out the else statement, the created_at value does not update after editing a product. Creating a new product adds the correct date to created_at. The only downside seems to be that you would need to make this change again if you update your Magento install, and your created_at dates will not update if you change your locale.